# Emacs: syntax highlight for non-code files

Tags: file, emacs, syntax-highlighting

Let's us suppose I want to create a file (using emacs) to explain something about programming. For example, a mylib-tutorial.txt.

Is there a way to turn on syntax highlight on specific parts of a file containing code?

For example:

```
Tutorial
---------
This call behaves as follow:

  void foo(&resource);

This call will provoke a huge stack overflow and all of your 
personal files will be permanent lost (a copy to the police
will be sent, though).
```

Is there is a way to turn on syntax highlight for the code sample? Org-mode perhaps?

Comment: If this is for your own use, you can also just put the whole buffer in the mode needed to highlight the code excerpts. That probably won't affect the non-code parts much. In that case, you need not change any of the text, i.e., no need to adapt the code sections to fit Org mode or whatever. Not that you will necessarily want to keep the buffer in that mode while you are editing non-code parts, but the point is that you can always change the mode temporarily to show whatever parts you want highlighted according to a given mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Enable `org-src-fontify-natively`](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/examples/fontify-src-code-blocks.html):

```
(eval-after-load "org"
  '(setq org-src-fontify-natively t))
```

And then use `org-mode`:

```
* Tutorial

This call behaves as follows:

#+BEGIN_SRC c
  void foo(&resource);
#+END_SRC

This call will provoke a huge stack overflow and all of your 
personal files will be permanent lost (a copy to the police
will be sent, though).
```

You can also edit the `SRC` block in `c-mode` using `org-edit-special`, bound to `C-c '` by default. Use `C-c '` again to close the `c-mode` buffer and update the Org buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do even better than just fontifying the region: using nxhtml-mode you can enable appropriate mode in the code region.

Here's a basic nxhtml setup:

```lisp
;; nxhtml-mode:
(load "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/nxhtml/autostart.el")
;; Mumamo is making emacs 23.3 freak out:
(when (and (equal emacs-major-version 23)
           (equal emacs-minor-version 3))
  (eval-after-load "bytecomp"
    '(add-to-list 'byte-compile-not-obsolete-vars
                  'font-lock-beginning-of-syntax-function))
  ;; tramp-compat.el clobbers this variable!
  (eval-after-load "tramp-compat"
    '(add-to-list 'byte-compile-not-obsolete-vars
                  'font-lock-beginning-of-syntax-function)))
(require 'mumamo)
(require 'mumamo-fun)
```

For example let's add a css code rule for rst-mode. In reStructuredText css code it demarked with

.. code-block:: css

p {
       text-align: right;
   }

Now let's write rules which specify that this should be in css-mode. For this open `nxhtml/util/mumamo-fun.el` and add there:

```lisp
(defun rst-bk-mumamo-css-regexp-chunk-start (pos max)
  (let ((where (mumamo-chunk-start-fw-re pos max "\\.\\. code-block:: css\\(.\\|\n\\)*?\n\n")))
    (when where
      (list where 'css-mode))))

(defun rst-bk-mumamo-css-regexp-chunk-end (pos max)
  (save-match-data
    (mumamo-chunk-end-fw-re pos max "\\(^[[:blank:]]+$\\|\n\\)+[^[:blank:]\n]")))

(defun rst-bk-mumamo-css-quick-regexp-chunk (pos
                                  min
                                  max)
  (save-match-data
    (mumamo-possible-chunk-forward pos max 'rst-bk-mumamo-css-regexp-chunk-start
                                           'rst-bk-mumamo-css-regexp-chunk-end)))

(defun rst-bk-mumamo-css-directive (pos min max)
  "Find css chunks. Return range and 'css-mode.
   See `mumamo-find-possible-chunk' for POS, MIN and MAX."
  (rst-bk-mumamo-css-quick-regexp-chunk pos min max))
```

Now let's regiester that as a new rst-mode:

```lisp
;;;###autoload
(define-mumamo-multi-major-mode rst-bk-mumamo-mode
  "Turn on multiple major modes for RestructuredText."
  ("ReST" rst-mode (
                    rst-bk-mumamo-css-directive
                    )))
```

and associate rst files with this new rst mode:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.rst\\'" . rst-bk-mumamo-mode))
```

Now you have you have a css-mode inside a css code-block in rst file:

[image]

[image]